# If form Submit, Submit form, and redirect to URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I would like to create something like 'if form submits' redirect user opening a new tab, to a specific URL. I would like to write this as a JavaScript function, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `on('submit', function () { ... })`:

```
$("form").on("submit", function () {
     window.location = "/redirectUrl";
     return false; // prevent refreshing page
});
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/pFQ9G/1/)

Most of browsers will [block the opening of a new tab](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4907843/1420197), so, just redirect the user on the new page.

---

But you can do it with HTML:

```
<form target="_blank" action="/redirectUrl"></form>
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/pFQ9G/)

Comment: `window.open(url, '_blank');`

Comment: @karaxuna Yes, I pasted the link. Most of browsers block new tab opening...

Answer (score 1):

You can write target attribute to form tag:

```
<form target="_blank"></form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('form').on('submit', function() {

    window.open('someurl');

    // Some code to do the submit

    // Prevent the submit
    return false;
});
```

<kbd>[REF window.open](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp)</kbd>

Comment: Sorry, but I have to say you that [W3Schools is bad](http://www.w3fools.com/).

Comment: @Johnツ I know that, but it has the correct info for this particular resource.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you, you need to open a new tab with an specific url, a part of the regular behaviour of the form submission.

Major browsers blocks opening a new window/tab on a non-user-click event.
So you need to bind an extra event on the submit button, but then **you can't control if submission was successful** (for example having a validator like jquery.validator).

```
$("#myform input[type=submit]").click(function() {
  window.open("http://www.site.com/");
});
```